# Span Child Object on Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I get this code to only execute its button:

```
​<span id="spanClicker">

<span id="subClicker">
            [Click Me]        
</span>
​</span>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

like this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rpCVy/

Comment: are you asking how can you make only click me button populate alert?

Comment: Could [Click Me] in some Html control? like label or span

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/malet/rpCVy/3/

You can use `e.stopPropagation()` to prevent the click event firing for both elements.

Also on a side note the `.live` function is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7 `.on` should be used instead.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you're looking for:

```
$( '#subClicker' ).on( 'click', function (e) {
    alert( 'subClicker' )

    // Now here is the magic you want:
    e.stopPropagation( )
} )
```

As you can guess, `e.stopPropagation()` allows you to prevent the event from propagating to its parent elements.

Comment: I am sure he could, but at first it would be nice if he would be more detailed with his question.

Comment: @Downvoters: OP didn't have the fiddle originally, I hope this new version of the answer is enough for you.

Comment: And whats up with down voting this answer?

Comment: The original answer wasn't like this, I didn't understand OP's question correctly because no fiddle was provided :)

Comment: then may be people should down vote the question : ) not your answer.

Comment: because i am still not sure what he actually looking for, there are two thing, he can either make sure his code does not trigger unnecessary action or prevent propagation.

Answer (score 2):

This ought to do it.

http://jsfiddle.net/rpCVy/2/

New javascript

```
$(function()
{
   $("#spanClicker").live("click",function()
   {
        alert('Span Clicked');                               
   });                           

    $("#subClicker").live("click",function(e)
      {
            alert('Button Clicked');
            e.stopPropagation();          
      });
});​
```

The anonymous function associated with `.click` can take an event for the first argument. Call the `stopPropagation()` method of the event object to stop the click event from bubbling up to containers of the target element of the event.